# C# showing only the values from sql table with null value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am connecting to an SQL server.  I have a column which has date and time and another which has the user name. Once i connect to the database it shows everything except the null values in the column of date and time. I need to show only the column of data and time which holds null values and the user with the null value.  How do i Display the null values but only the null values?

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[]args)
{

        string conn=null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        conn=("Data Source=Database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Table;User ID=user;Password=example");

         connection=new SqlConnection(conn);
         try{

             connection.Open();
             Console.Writeline("Connection Open!");
             SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledateandtime,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull]");
             cmd.Connection = connection;
             SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while(reader.Read())
              {

                   Console.WriteLine("{1} , {0}", reader["tabledateandtime"].ToString(),  reader["tableuser"].ToString()));

               }

               connection.Close();
                }

                catch(Exception ex)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

                }
            }
      }
```

Comment: If I understand corrctly all you need to do is change `SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledateandtime,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull]");` to `SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledateandtime,tableuser FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull] WHERE tabledateandtime IS NULL OR tableuser IS NULL");`

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri yeah pretty much thats what i need to do

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri but tableuser will never be null just it will show the user connected to the null value

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understood what you want - check this out:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{1} , {0}", reader["tabledateandtime"] == DBNull.Value ? "NULL" : reader["tabledateandtime"].ToString(),  reader["tableuser"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: okay this worked can you show me how i can show another table like tabledateandtime and i need to display its null values also.  In the same program.

Comment: I would need the table name and column names for the null columns

Comment: i have 3 tables 1. TableIn 2. TableOut 3.TableUser.  Now i need to show the null values of tablein and table out and near them the user with this null value.

Comment: This seems more complex than I thought. Please create another question and include more details such as the tables' structure and which columns you need to check for null.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's last comment, I have updated the code below to display NULL if the date is NULL otherwise show the date.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{1}, {0}", 
       reader["tableuser"].ToString(),  
       reader["tabledateandtime"] == DBNull.Value ? "NULL" : reader["tabledateandtime"].ToString());
}
```

If you just want to return only records that have a null date, then just update your SQL to this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tabledateandtime, tableuser" +
    " FROM [dbo].[tb_Showingnull] WHERE tabledateandtime IS NULL OR tableuser IS NULL");
```

Comment: Why not just filter out null values from database itself?

Comment: @danish ok, I have added that option.

Comment: @Donal  i dont think you understood exactly what i have to do.  i have a list with date and time but some are null.  I need to display in the command run on one side the user and on the other side the value saying null.

Comment: I need to do the second one but when I am doing it as you are telling me it tells me "incorrect syntax near '.' "

Comment: @bobby the syntax is correct, I have checked - can you try copy and paste.